# FingerprintAuth undefined in NativeModules

Tags: react-native, touch-id, android-fingerprint-api

I am using [react-native-touch-id](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id). iOS works fine but got issues with the android.

`TouchID.authenticate()
.then()
.catch(error => {
});`

The above snippet gives
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined`

When I dig into the node_modules, in file TouchId.android.js, there is FingerprintAuth undefined in NativeModules.

`RN: 0.57.2`
I have tried removing the node_modules and re-setup the library, but same problem occurs.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/hieuvp/react-native-fingerprint-scanner/issues/58#issuecomment-429626522 this issue is similar to react-native-touch-id